# Make struct pointing to different struct in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
class IntComponent
{
   public int size;
}

class IntReferenceComponent : IntComponent
{
   public IntComponent target; // keep my size same as target size

   private void OnValidate()
   {
     //triggered on target assignment
   }
}
```

Is it possible in C# make struct variable pointing to different struct variable like with objects ? Even with unsafe pointers ?

**Edit**

The final solution according to Charlieface solution:

```
public abstract class StructComponent<T> where T : struct
{
   public T size;
}
public class IntComponent : StructComponent<int>{ }

public class IntReferenceComponent : IntComponent
{
  public IntComponent target; 

  public new int size
  {
    get => target.size;
    set => target.size = value;
  }
}
```

In Unity I had to create custom editor:

```
public abstract class StructComponentEditor<T, D> : Editor where T : struct where D : StructComponent<T>
{
   public static object StructField(string label, T value, params GUILayoutOption[] options)
   {
     switch (value)
     {
       case Vector3 v:
           return EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field(label, v, options);
       case Vector2 v:
           return EditorGUILayout.Vector2Field(label, v, options);
       case float f:
           return EditorGUILayout.FloatField(label, f, options);
       case int i:
           return EditorGUILayout.IntField(label, i, options);
       case double d:
           return EditorGUILayout.DoubleField(label, d, options);
       case Color c:
           return EditorGUILayout.ColorField(label, c, options);
     }

     return null;
  }

  public void DrawDefaultStructComponent()
  {
    D target = serializedObject.targetObject as D;

    PropertyInfo sizeProp = target.GetType().GetProperty("size");

    object value;

    try
    {
      value = sizeProp.GetValue(target);
    }
    catch
    {
      value = new T();
    }

    if(sizeProp.SetMethod != null)
    {
      sizeProp.SetValue(target, StructField("Size", (T)value));
      return;
    }

    StructField("Size", (T)value);
  }

  public override void OnInspectorGUI()
  {
    DrawDefaultStructComponent();

    DrawDefaultInspector();
  }
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(StructComponent<int>), true)]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class IntComponentEditor : StructComponentEditor<int, StructComponent<int>> { }
```

I need to write something because most of it is just code :)))))) So thanks to everyone who helped :) I love you <3

Comment: `ref int b = ref a;`?

Comment: I want to say you can do this with ref parameters but not with variables, but you can probably do something like this in an "unsafe" context, and there are new fancy features in newer C# versions that I'm not 100% up to speed with (since I'm still stuck using .NET Framework 4.0).

Comment: What are you trying to do? If something is a `struct`, it is an object in the general sense, but it is naturally a value. Part of it's value can be a reference to another object, but that object would need to be a reference type (i.e. a class) rather than a value type. Newer versions of C# have `ref struct`, but their use is tightly constrained to a single stack frame (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#ref-struct). Is there some problem you are looking to solve with this (if so, what), or are you trying to settle a bar bet.

Comment: @Flydog57 my problem is that i have a class with int prop. Then i have two classes that inherit from it so they have both the int prop. Now i need one of the classes to keep the same value as the target class. I solve this by creating action onValueChange that is triggered on setter of the int prop. I wanted to know if there is some better solution.

Comment: @GSerg Thanks. Actually it didn’t solve my problem but thanks anyway. I thought that ref can be used only in methods.

Comment: @GSerg I would need to do something like int b = ref a. Not ref int b = ref a.

Comment: @GSerg Because int b is defined in base class so i cannot change it to ref.

Comment: @DaveCousineau yea we are on the same boat

Comment: I don't understand what _"Now i need one of the classes to keep the same value as the target class."_ means (in particular, what's the _target class_).  Classes don't have values, instances have values.  If you have classes `Animal`, `Dog` and `Chicken`, and `Animal` has an `int NumLegs {get; set;}` property, then both Dog and Chicken do as well.  If you have a Dog instance (NumLegs== 4) then it is necessarily an Animal instance as well.  What are you trying to do.  Please show more code

Comment: @Flydog57 Animal, Dog, Chicken. Chicken has 2 legs. Dog has prop Animal targetAnimal. Now if targetAnimal is chicken i want to change num of legs to 2. If i change chickens num of legs to 3 then dogs num of legs will change to 3 too.

Comment: You'll need to come up with an example that makes more sense.  There's no way to guess that's what you are talking about from your `int a = 0; int b = a;` code.  My example falls apart (and my mind explodes) when you start changing the number of legs on a chicken.  Show us what you are talking about (by editing your question, not by adding a comment)

Comment: Move details of your question from comments to body of the question- why you need it, what you tried, why you do not like the solution that you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do this in your case, and generally it would be ill-advised to try and mess around with pointers in normal Object Oriented cases, as you don't normally expose the internals of a class.

Instead, just use composition, with an outer property exposing the value of the inner object

```cs
class IntReferenceComponent : IntComponent
{
    public IntComponent target; // keep my size same as target size

    public int Size
    {
        get => target.size;
        set => target.size = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You Can not do this with `struct` since its value type means you only can take a copy from it and you can't use it as a pointer as you do with classes

> #### Below Code shows that even with pointers unsafe code will not work because you, in the end, will copy the values to a struct to use them,
>
> since you can't access the object attribute with the `pointer` that
> just `point to the object itself  (this is what I know )

```
namespace Feto
{
    internal struct Complex
    {
        public float real;
        public float imag;

        public Complex(float real, float image)
        {
            this.real = real;
            this.imag = image;

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $" Class Complex {this.real} , {this.imag}";
        }
    }
    class FixingComplex 
    {

        public float real;
        public float imag;
        public FixingComplex(float real, float image)
        {
            this.real = real;
            this.imag = image;

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $" Class Complex {this.real} , {this.imag}";
        }
    }

    unsafe class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            Complex x = new Complex(10, 20);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Complex* y = &x;
            //address of stuct
            Console.WriteLine((int)&x);
            //the y point to it
            Console.WriteLine((int)y);
            //what z point to
            Console.WriteLine(*y);
            //send the addresss of the stuct
            addNumbers(y);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadKey();

            void addNumbers(Complex* result)
            {
                //make sure it is the same address of stuct
                Console.WriteLine((int)result);
                //now here we got the address of struct we need to modify it
                Console.WriteLine(*result);
                //Here is the problem it will take copy 
                var value = *result;
                value.real = 8888;
                value.imag = 8888;
                //you can use fixedcomplex to go on with pointers and workaround
                .....
            }




        }


    }

}
```

## But there is a Solution

#### with small modifications like passing the address as a reference, not a copy of the address this will workaround  and change the values and

> The Changes  `addNumbers(ref y);`            `void addNumbers(ref Complex* result)`              `*result = new Complex(8888,8888);`

```
namespace Feto
{
    internal struct Complex
    {
        public float real;
        public float imag;

        public Complex(float real, float image)
        {
            this.real = real;
            this.imag = image;

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $" Class Complex {this.real} , {this.imag}";
        }
    }
    class FixingComplex 
    {

        public float real;
        public float imag;
        public FixingComplex(float real, float image)
        {
            this.real = real;
            this.imag = image;

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $" Class Complex {this.real} , {this.imag}";
        }
    }

    unsafe class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            Complex x = new Complex(10, 20);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Complex* y = &x;
            //address of stuct
            Console.WriteLine((int)&x);
            //the y point to it
            Console.WriteLine((int)y);
            //what z point to
            Console.WriteLine(*y);
            //send the addresss of the stuct
            addNumbers(ref y);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadKey();

            void addNumbers(ref Complex* result)
            {
                //make sure it is the same address of stuct
                Console.WriteLine((int)result);
                //now here we got the address of struct we need to modify it
                Console.WriteLine(*result);
                //Here is the problem it will take copy 
                //var value = *result;
                *result = new Complex(8888,8888);
                //you can use fixedcomplex to go on with pointers and workaround
                
            }




        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Yea i know the definition. But i was wondering if there is some dark magic that could be used. Because adding and removing listener to action onValueChange is kinda anoying and triggering the action every time the value is changed is probebly not performance happy

Comment: @Panakvina321 i think you can try unsafe pointers, You can also pass structs by reference (in a similar way like you pass variables of built-in type by reference) `void addNumbers(complex *result)`  and you pass `&struct` the address try this out, make sure you enable the unsafe mode this might help https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointer-functions

Comment: Looks like this is what i need. Do you think these unsafe operations will work with Unity ?

Comment: @Panakvina321  of course it will i trying it out for you to check if it work and i will reply here for you

Comment: @Panakvina321 I solved it Panakvina check the solution, and if this is what you want please consider accepting the answer

Comment: Yep seems like its working. I didnt test it with unity. Im not sure if serializefield gonna be happy with that. But it is the solution. Thanks. Gonna reply after test.